# Installing new GPU with drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, amd

I am currently upgrading my PC from an AMD 5700XT to an RTX 3070 which use different drivers (duh).

The drivers i currently have installed are the xf86-video-amdgpu Packages from arch as well as openCL and some other amd related Packages:

libva-mesa-driver lib32-libva-mesa-driver mesa-vdpau lib32-mesa-vdpau libva-vdpau-driver lib32-libva-vdpau-driver amdvlk lib32-amdvlk

Should i uninstall those packages BEFORE or AFTER installing my new gpu? Any other precautions I should take?

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue. The proprietary nvidia drivers will only conflict with noveau, which will be automatically blacklisted for you if you install the drivers via your distro's package.

Comment: Ok so i just popout my amd graphics card, plug the nvidia one in and install the drivers for it (and ofc also uninstall amd drivers). I assume its gonna be running on some form of Universal vga driver until i installed proper ones? Also i got radeon profile installed now. Does a similar thing exist to nvidia? Or do i have to use their driver Software which i heard is bad on linux

Comment: Either order should be fine, but if you do install the graphics card first it should not be an issue. noveau is fine for normal desktop use, just not for games. Just be sure to follow instructions specific to your distro for install as the way they handle nvidia drivers does vary. I don't know what radeon profile is but nvidia has nvidia-settings and it's been unimproved since I first used it over 10 years ago.

Comment: All went smoothly ty. I am using proprietary btw since i rely on rendering on my gpu so need every bit of performance. Didnt have a working output of video in linux tho until i installed drivers over the commandline interface without a UI. Wasnt a problem tho but i am not sure if thats supposed to happen